# Run junit tests on eclipse filtered by Name

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit

How can I run all testes that ends with "IT" on enclipse?

See, by default I have tests class that ends with "Test" or "IT" end I just wanna run the ones ended by "IT".

Comment: Is this a maven project?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution would be to use a `Suite` with the required tests classes listed.  E.g. :

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ FirstIT.class, SecondIT.class })
public class TestSuite {

}
```

This class could then be run directly as a test in Eclipse

---

Otherwise, something like the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library could be used to do the scanning:

```
@RunWith(ReflectionsScanner.class)
public class ReflectionsScanner extends Suite {
    public ReflectionsScanner(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder)
            throws InitializationError {
        super(builder, klass, getAnnotatedClasses());
    }

    private static Class<?>[] getAnnotatedClasses() {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package",
                new SubTypesScanner(false));
        Set<String> allTypes = reflections.getAllTypes();
        Class<?>[] matchingClasses = allTypes.stream()
                .filter(name -> name.endsWith("IT")).map(name -> {
            try {
                return Class.forName(name);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
            }
        }).toArray(Class[]::new);
        return matchingClasses;
    }
}
```

`reflections.getAllTypes()` can be a bit too much sometimes - there's also `getSubTypesOf()` and `getTypesAnnotatedWith()` that might provide a simpler filter.  The link above explains this in more detail.

---

Another simple route is to use multiple source folders for two types of tests - e.g. `src/test/java` and `src/it/java` if using Maven.  Then Eclipse will let you Run As/Unit Test directly against the parent folders.

For Maven, you would then need to add that [test source directory](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html#Add_more_test_source_directories_to_your_project).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look to [@IncludeClassNamePatterns](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/suite/api/IncludeClassNamePatterns.html) annotation. It belongs to Junit 5, which should work on Eclipse Oxygene.1a+.